# Top bar show when transition to the root view controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a swift app,

in my app, I want to restart the app (or transition to the root view controller) after login or logout.

i used that code to restart my app

```
 func restartApplication () {
    let initialViewController  =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
     
     let navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
     guard
             let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow,
             let rootViewController = window.rootViewController
             else {
         return
     }

     navCtrl.view.frame = rootViewController.view.frame
     rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
     window.isHidden = false
     
     UIView.transition( with: window, duration: 0.3, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {

         window.rootViewController = navCtrl
     })

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
navCtrl.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```